# How can I clear the PropertyModel's value when I hit back on my browser

Tags: apache, wicket

I have a DropDownChoice with a PropertyModel in my page and I have some other actions which take me to different pages. Now when I click on the Back Arrow on my browser, I come to my page which has the DropDownChoice with the previously selected choice. I understand PropertyModel holds the value for me. But how can I get rid of it when I hit Back button and why is the onBeforeRender(both on the class as well the Component) not working when I hit the Back button. Please comment if my explanation is not clear enough. I am using Wicket 1.4.8

Comment: You'll also have to handle Firefox remembering form values when you use forward / back.

Comment: But its not the browser because its happening in all the browsers. That's one and the second thing is this should be irrelevant to the browser caching. That's what got me and I still couldn't get any information about this anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onBeforeRender doesn't work because it's never called. When you navigating using "Back" button, no new request are sended to your server, hence page rendering never occurs. The only way to solve your problem - is to use javascript.

Comment: That actually helps. I was thinking which there is no call happening.